# Should address, city and state be nullable columns in my MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

The client table on my database has the name, address, city and state columns.

I always thought that a better design (easier to manage later in the code) would be to set all columns of a table to NOT NULL.

But now, I'm kinda stuck moving spaces in address, city and state when a new client is added, and I don't really need these columns to be populated on an insert.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: NULLable sounds like what you want for these columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving spaces"?

Comment: You could use `default ''` instead of allowing them to be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for you ideas, I guess I'm just going to convert these columns to NULL. What i've been doing in php is moving a space ('  ') to these columns to make sure they are not null, but then, when editing the rows, the placeholders in my forms were not showing because these fields had a space in them. thanks guys